# How install composer?

Tags: php, installation, composer-php

I downloaded the project.
My task to run this project through the xampp server.
They told me to install composter to the server.

I downloaded the project into htdocs/mysite/
I install composer
**C:\bin>php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"**

He called through **С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar**

When I run project Dependencies are not tightened(yii,...)

when I 
**С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar create project C:/...htdocs/mysite/**

Error:InvalidArgumentExeption
**Cannot find project  with stability stable**

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be relevant to OP question for anyone looking to install composer

**Linux - Ubuntu**

`sudo apt-get install composer`

Or ..

Manual installation based on getcomposer.org

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

run these command in a bash file or one by one.

Or ..

```
# this answer is copied and not tested

curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Get latest stable version of composer

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/download/latest-stable/composer.phar
```

Move to bin

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've read this correctly, are you trying to install yii?

If so, this guide should help:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer/

It has a link to a sample Github project too.